# Eliminar o ignorar duplicados de una lista de tuplas filtrado por el elemento [0] de cada tupla

Tags: python

```
A=[('0001', 'LUCIANO MENENDEZ', '809-981-8958', 'ROBO ZONA #05', datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 9, 22, 20, 14, 504000), 'LUCIANO DE LEON MENENDEZ', '809-333-3335'), ('7575', 'CLIENTE DE PRUEBA', '809-748-1737', 'ROBO ZONA #01', datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 9, 23, 5, 32, 131000), 'LUCIANO', '809-333-3335'), ('7575', 'CLIENTE DE PRUEBA', '809-748-1737', 'ROBO ZONA #02', datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 9, 22, 20, 41, 906000), 'LUCIANO', '809-333-3335'), ('7575', 'CLIENTE DE PRUEBA', '809-748-1737', 'ROBO ZONA #05', datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 9, 22, 20, 38, 405000), 'LUCIANO', '809-333-3335'), ('7575', 'CLIENTE DE PRUEBA', '809-748-1737', 'ROBO ZONA #08', datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 9, 22, 19, 48, 705000), 'LUCIANO', '809-333-3335'), ('9999', 'ERNESTINA MENENDEZ', '809-988-0124', 'ROBO ZONA #08', datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 9, 22, 20, 2, 360000), 'LUCIANO MENENDEZ', '809-333-3335')]
```

teniendo esa lista

quisiera crear otra lista con los valores agrupados por el item 7575, 9999,0001 en este caso, porque estos valores cambian. pero siempre van a estar por ejemplo en A[1][0]
en el indice 0 de cada tupla.

Quisiera que quedara algo como:

```
('7575', 'CLIENTE DE PRUEBA', '809-748-1737', 'ROBO ZONA #08 Y ROBO ZONA #05 Y ROBO ZONA #02 Y ROBO ZONA #01', datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 9, 22, 19, 48, 705000), 'LUCIANO', '809-333-3335')
```

Que solo quede una fecha hora, la mas baja o la mas alta, no importa

lo he intentado con groupby:

```
result=[(k, ([e[3] for e in g])) for k, g in groupby(A, lambda x:x[0])]
```

pero no se como sacar los demas valores que deseo.
alguna idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando usas `groupby()` obtienes un iterador que te permite iterar por los grupos. Cada vez que iteras obtienes una pareja de valores (`k` y `g` en tu código). Esa pareja consiste en:

- `k`: es la "clave" del grupo. Depende del criterio que hayas usado para agrupar. En tu caso al agrupar por el primer elemento de cada tupla, las claves son precisamente las cadenas "7575", "9999", "0001", etc
- `g` es "el grupo". Se trata de otro iterador. Si iteras por él, obtienes cada elemento del grupo (la tupla completa, por lo que en este caso de nuevo aparecerá en primer lugar de esa tupla la clave de agrupación).

Como ves, ya que en este caso todos los elementos del grupo contienen la tupla completa, no necesitamos en realidad la clave `k`, pues esta ya formará parte del resultado. Por otro lado, lo que quieres hacer es tomar un elemento cualquiera de `g`. Dices que por ejemplo el que tenga la fecha más alta. Éste podrías obtenerlo haciendo `max()` sobre `g`, y usando como función key la que extraiga el campo de la fecha (que es el campo de índice 4).

Para extraer campos puedes usar lambdas como has hecho en tu ejemplo, o ser un poco más "funcional" y utilizar `operator.itemgetter(i)`, que en el fondo programa para tí esa lambda que extrae un ítem, en concreto el que tenga índice `i`.

Así que usando estos trucos, lo que buscas se obtendría así:

```py
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

resultado = [max(g, key=itemgetter(4)) for k, g in groupby(A, itemgetter(0))]
```

Y sobre tus datos de entrada produce el siguiente `resultado`:

```py
[('0001',
  'LUCIANO MENENDEZ',
  '809-981-8958',
  'ROBO ZONA #05',
  datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 9, 22, 20, 14, 504000),
  'LUCIANO DE LEON MENENDEZ',
  '809-333-3335'),
 ('7575',
  'CLIENTE DE PRUEBA',
  '809-748-1737',
  'ROBO ZONA #01',
  datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 9, 23, 5, 32, 131000),
  'LUCIANO',
  '809-333-3335'),
 ('9999',
  'ERNESTINA MENENDEZ',
  '809-988-0124',
  'ROBO ZONA #08',
  datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 9, 22, 20, 2, 360000),
  'LUCIANO MENENDEZ',
  '809-333-3335')]
```

### Otra idea

Solo para que tengas más claro cómo se usan los grupos, imagina que en lugar de querer quedarte con el que tenga la fecha más alta, decides quedarte con el primer resultado de cada grupo, sea éste el que sea. Si `g` fuese una lista, bastaría quedarse con `g[0]`, pero debido a que `groupby()` no retorna listas sino iteradores, un intento de acceder a `g[0]` fallará.

Naturalmente puedes convertirlo en lista y hacer `list(g)[0]`, pero hay un mecanismo un poco más limpio. Cuando tienes un generador, hacer `next()` sobre ese generador te devuelve su primer elemento (si haces `next()` otra vez te devuelve el segundo, etc. y si haces `next()` tras el último elemento obtendrías una excepción).

Así que podemos usar `next(g)` para extraer el primer elemento de cada grupo:

```
resultado = [next(g) for k, g in groupby(A, itemgetter(0))]
```

## Edición

Al parecer no se trata solo de tomar un solo registro de cada grupo `g`, sino de **combinar** varios registros en uno solo. La regla para esta combinación sería:

- Los campos 0, 1, 2, 5 y 6 se tomarían de cualquiera de los registros del grupo, ya que se entiende que tienen el mismo valor en todos los registros.
- El campo 3 (descripción de robos) se construiría concatenando ese campo entre todos los registros del grupo (mediante la conjunción "Y")
- El campo 4 (fecha) se tomaría usando la fecha más reciente de todas las del grupo.

La solución que propongo usará los campos 0, 1, 2, 5 y 6 del primer registro del grupo. Por desgracia eso hace la sintaxis más fea y difícil de leer, y también obliga a un bucle  `for` explícito en lugar de una comprensión de listas:

```py
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

resultado = []
for k, g in groupby(A, itemgetter(0)):
  g = list(g)    # Convertir el grupo en lista
  resultado.append((g[0][0], g[0][1], g[0][2], " Y ".join(t[3] for t in g), max(t[4] for t in g), g[0][5], g[0][6]))
```

Fijate que convierto primero el grupo en una lista, para así poder usar `g[0]` para acceder al primer registro dentro de ese grupo, y para poder también iterar por el grupo (`for t in g`) a la hora de crear los campos con la descripción del robo y la fecha.

El resultado del código anterior es:

```
[('0001',
  'LUCIANO MENENDEZ',
  '809-981-8958',
  'ROBO ZONA #05',
  datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 9, 22, 20, 14, 504000),
  'LUCIANO DE LEON MENENDEZ',
  '809-333-3335'),
 ('7575',
  'CLIENTE DE PRUEBA',
  '809-748-1737',
  'ROBO ZONA #01 Y ROBO ZONA #02 Y ROBO ZONA #05 Y ROBO ZONA #08',
  datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 9, 23, 5, 32, 131000),
  'LUCIANO',
  '809-333-3335'),
 ('9999',
  'ERNESTINA MENENDEZ',
  '809-988-0124',
  'ROBO ZONA #08',
  datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 9, 22, 20, 2, 360000),
  'LUCIANO MENENDEZ',
  '809-333-3335')]
```

Otra variación del código que, aunque un poco más larga, creo que resulta ligeramente más legible, podría ser la siguiente:

```py
resultado = []
for k, g in groupby(A, itemgetter(0)):
  g = list(g)           # Convertir el grupo en una lista
  record = list(g[0])   # Copiar el primer registro del grupo
  # Y ahora reemplazar en ese registro los campos 3 y 4
  record[3] = " Y ".join(t[3] for t in g)
  record[4] = max(t[4] for t in g)
  # Añadir ese registro (como tupla) al resultado
  resultado.append(tuple(record))
```

### Ampliación

Ante el último comentario pidiendo cómo evitar valores repetidos en el "robo", la cosa puede ser tan simple como usar un conjunto (`set()`). Este tipo de datos python elimina automáticamente los duplicados.

El código quedaría así (solo cambia una línea respecto del anterior):

```
resultado = []
for k, g in groupby(A, itemgetter(0)):
  g = list(g)           # Convertir el grupo en una lista
  record = list(g[0])   # Copiar el primer registro del grupo
  # Y ahora reemplazar en ese registro los campos 3 y 4
  record[3] = " Y ".join(set(t[3] for t in g))   # <----- AQUI se añade set()
  record[4] = max(t[4] for t in g)
  # Añadir ese registro (como tupla) al resultado
  resultado.append(tuple(record))
```

A `set()` se le está pasando la lista de robos de un grupo (`t[3] for t in g`). Cada vez que un robo que ya estaba en el conjunto vuelve a aparecer, el conjunto lo almacena una sola vez. Después el conjunto resultante se le pasa a `.join()` que es quien concatena los elementos (ya no hay repetidos) usando "Y".

Comment: En caso de que desee concatenar los valores del indice 3 cuando el indice 0 sea el mismo como lo haria. ejemplo para el 7575 que concatene ('ROBO ZONA #08 Y ROBO ZONA #05 Y ROBO ZONA #02 Y ROBO ZONA #01')

Comment: @user2805899 No me había dado cuenta de que ya pedías esa concatenación en la pregunta original. He editado la respuesta para añadirlo.

Comment: Era todo lo que necesitaba, eres un crack

Comment: Si hay valores repetidos en  el indice 3, ejemplo (Robo zona #06 y Robo zona #06 y Robo zona #04 y Robo zona #06) como hacer que solo incluya un valor de los repetidos

Comment: Respondido en la ampliación

Comment: record[3] = "ROBO"+ ",".join(set(t[3].replace("ROBO","") for t in g))   # <----- AQUI se añade set()                                                                                                                         ,he realizado ese cambio para que salga                                                            ROBO ZONA #02, ZONA #01, ZONA #08, ZONA #05                                        ,no se si hay alguna mejor manera de hacerlo, gracias de nuevo, he aprendido mucho con tus explicaciones

Comment: A lo mejor te gusta esta otra opción:  `record[3] = "ROBO ZONAS: " + ", ".join(set(t[3].split()[-1] for t in g))`, que se queda solo con los números de zona y crea una cadena tal que: "ROBO ZONAS: #02, #01, #08, #05". Por cierto, si la respuesta te ha servido puedes marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: Me gusta tu ultima sugerencia. Le di a aceptar desde tu primera respuesta.